# C# create click event for onclick JavaScript doPostBack

Tags: javascript, c#, dopostback

The problem is that when I click on that button postback is not happening, ie the button click event does not fire, When I view source on the page it shows me on the button onclick

javascript:

```
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("GridView1:_ctl2:lnkRemove", "", true, "", "", false, true))
```

any suggestion on javascript click event for postback in c#?

Comment: please post your c# and asp.net code

Comment: can we see the code relating to this